# summarize categorical data based on grouping

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a data frame in the following form

```
Id <- c(101,102,103,101,103,103,102,101,103,102)
Service <- c('A','B','A','C','A','A','B','C','A','B')
Type <- c('C','I','C','I','C','C','C','I','I','C')
Channel <- c('ATM1','ATM2','ATM1','Teller','Teller','ATM2','ATM1','ATM1','ATM2','Teller')
amount <- c(11,34,56,37,65,83,26,94,34,55)

df <- data.frame(Id,Service,Channel,Type,amount)
```

df in tabular formate

```
Id Service Channel Type amount
101       A    ATM1    C     11
102       B    ATM2    I     34
103       A    ATM1    C     56
101       C  Teller    I     37
103       A  Teller    C     65
103       A    ATM2    C     83
102       B    ATM1    C     26
101       C    ATM1    I     94
103       A    ATM2    I     34
102       B  Teller    C     55
```

I am able to summarize my data using `amount` column as `df %>% group_by(Id) %>% summarise(total = sum(amount)) %>% as.data.frame`

```
 Id total
101   142
102   115
103   238
```

How can I summarize data in a similar way using categorical columns (Service/Type/Channel) and `group_by(Id)`? I know we can use `table()` here, but I am trying to create a data frame, which I can use it for further analysis, such as clustering.

Comment: Is it `group_by(id, Service, Type, Channel)` you're looking for or your problem is more complicated?

Comment: @PoGibas yes I have tried this, grouping over each categorical variable and then looking at the amount spent by per ```customer Id```, But then it was of no use. My goal is to run cluster analysis later on to find customer segments based on Id. I just don't know what type of aggregation we can do on categorical features on my dataset.

I just don't know how to proceed in this case. Here is the original problem link as well
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26124/best-algorithm-to-create-segment-in-case-of-categorical-variables

Comment: Please post your desired output as it is not clear what you are looking for. If the question is what is a good format for cluster analysis, then SO might not be the best place to search for an answer.

Comment: The actual question does'nt make any sense as such. OP is not clear what exactly should be output.

Comment: Cluster analysis requires all continuous variables. Therefore, the categorical variables must be converted to dummy coded variables before summarizing to one row per `Id`.

Comment: Note that its beyond the scope of this question as to whether cluster analysis is the correct technique to use with this data, as that question is better addressed on the [Data Science SO Community](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26124/best-algorithm-to-create-segment-in-case-of-categorical-variables/26144#26144).

Answer (score 2):

One way to restructure the categorical variables in a manner that they can be summarized by `Id` is to create dummy coded variables, where 1 means presence, 0 means absence. Then, aggregate results in counts of each category (i.e. number of times ATM 1 used) by Id.

We use the `dummies` package to create dummy coded variables.

```
Id <- c(101,102,103,101,103,103,102,101,103,102)
Service <- c('A','B','A','C','A','A','B','C','A','B')
Type <- c('C','I','C','I','C','C','C','I','I','C')
Channel <- c('ATM1','ATM2','ATM1','Teller','Teller','ATM2','ATM1','ATM1','ATM2','Teller')
amount <- c(11,34,56,37,65,83,26,94,34,55)

df <- data.frame(Id,Service,Channel,Type,amount)
library(dummies)
df <- dummy.data.frame(df,names=c("Service","Type","Channel"))
aggregate(. ~ Id,data=df,"sum")
```

...and the output:

```
> aggregate(. ~ Id,data=df,"sum")
   Id ServiceA ServiceB ServiceC ChannelATM1 ChannelATM2 ChannelTeller TypeC
1 101        1        0        2           2           0             1     1
2 102        0        3        0           1           1             1     2
3 103        4        0        0           1           2             1     3
  TypeI amount
1     2    142
2     1    115
3     1    238
>
```

We interpret the results as follows.

Id 101 used Service A once, Service C twice, ATM1 once, a Teller once, Type I once, and Type C twice for a total amount of 142.